# regex matching Title-case or ALLCAPS with unicode chars

Tags: c#, regex

I understand that in .net you can use \p{Lu} to match all caps and \p{Lt} to match title case words, however I don't know how to combine them to match names that have unicode characters and can have between two and five words.

TL;DR, the regex I'm looking for should match:

JUAN PÉREZ
Juan Andrés Pérez
Juan Perez
JUAN ANDRES PEREZ GOMEZ
Juan Andrés Pérez Gómez

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure about your requirement. Can't you just use `\p{L}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments indicate, it seems this should work:

`^([\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]\p{L}+\s*){2,5}`

Comment: Guess, he wants each word to start with `[\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]`